# ImportError: No module named in python

Tags: python-3.x, import

I'm trying to run my python script on ubuntu server. I'm using python 3.4.

My directory tree looks like this:

```
home/papers/project/Daniel/filepaths.py
home/papers/project/Daniel/run_get_analysis.py
home/papers/project/Daniel/combine_num/get_analysis.py
```

The script`run_get_analysis.py` runs the script `get_analysis.py`, and inside `get_analysis.py` I have:

```
from Daniel.filepaths import scripts_output_path
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
from Daniel.filepaths import scripts_output_path
ImportError: No module named 'Daniel'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What directory are you running the script with `from.Daniel...` from ?

Comment: I'm running the script 'run_get_analysis.py'